# Database with variable number of fields in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relationship, normalization

Note: This is for a personal project to help in self learning, it does not involve work or schooling.

I'm new to creating/databases and I'm looking for insight in how I could design the most logically sound table relationships.

To give a bit of background information: I want to design a database that will hold different alcoholic drinks such as cocktails, beers, wines, etc. The database will contain fields such as the drink ID, name, description, and finally, the ingredients.

The issue I'm having is in trying to wrap my head around the logic of having a variable number of ingredients for a drink. For example, one cocktail might only have 2 ingredients while another might have 4,5,6, etc.

So far I have created this design (It does not appear logically sound from my point of view and have gotten stuck trying to figure out the best way to store the information).

```
**Drinks table**

Drink ID

Drink name

Drink description

Drink category     // Beer, Cocktails, 

Drink type    // Pale ale, Lager, etc.

**Cocktails Table**

Drink ID

Drink instructions

**Beers Table**

Drink ID

**Ingredients Table**

Ingredient id

Ingredient name
```

---

I would be very grateful for any insight provided, thank you.

Comment: No need for excessive lines on the formating. It was in a good shape after my first edit. I would you change it?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed I had added a field in one of the tables that didn't belong and didn't realize that I screwed up the edit, honest mistake

Comment: Remove the Cocktails and Beers tables. Those are just different drinks, and you can add an "Instructions" field to the Drink table for the cocktails. The Ingedients table is the right way to handle ingredients. I'd just a numeric field for qty and text field for measurement (ie: 2 oz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for:

```
**Drinks table**
   ID
   name
   description
   category_id    //foreign key to a category table 
   type_id        //foreign key to a type table

**Category** //Beer, Cocktails, etc
   ID
   Name

**Type** //Pale ale, Lager, etc.
   ID
   Name

**Ingredients** //Hold all ingredients
   Id
   description

**Category_Ingredients** //That category has ingredients
   category_id
   Ingredient_id
   amount //if you want be perfectionist
```

This will allow you to have well defined data. You could specialize the drinks, say if a client like some specific ingredient you can add a table to a drink ingredient like:

```
 **Drink_ingredient**
    id_drink
    id_ingredient
    amount
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the insight! This is exactly what I was looking for and now feel a little bit silly for not being able to wrap my head around it in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Cocktails and Beers tables. Those are just different drinks, and you can add an "Instructions" field to the Drink table for the cocktails. The Ingedients table is the right way to handle ingredients. I'd just a numeric field for qty and text field for measurement (ie: 2 oz)

Comment: Great thanks for the help, to add, how can I deal with having multiple different ingredients for a drink in consideration that the ingredient ID would be a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to define cocktails as lists of ingredients, you need an `Ingredient` table for description of your ingredients, and a `CocktailIngredient` "cross-table" that says how much of each ingredient a cocktail takes:

`Ingredient` table:

```
id name
-- ------
1  vodka
2  Kahlua
3  Cream
...
```

`Cocktail` table:

```
id  name
--  -------------
 1  Black Russian
 2  White Russian
```

Now for the the most interesting part, the `CocktailIngredient` table:

```
c_id i_id parts
---- ---- -----
   1    1     5
   1    2     2
   2    1     5
   2    2     2
   2    3     3
```

This last table says that "Black Russian" (`c_id = 1`) takes five parts of vodka (`i_id=1`) and two parts of Kahlua (`i_id = 2`).

**Note:** If you can figure out proportions for "White Russian" from the table above, you have understood the many-to-many solution.